# Recommended iPhone Development Resources

Tags: ios

This is my first post here and I wanted to get some input from people doing iPhone development.  Other than the Apple DevCenter, where are there good sites to learn iPhone developement?

I know Apple has a tough NDA but there has to be people talking about writing applications for the iPhone.

Comment: Covered. Search around. There has been a lot of contribution to the site already. Welcome! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development)

Comment: [The Really Big List of iPhone SDK Development Links](http://appsamuck.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/28/the-really-big-list-of-iphone-sdk-development-links/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.icodeblog.com/tag/iphone/) covers some of the basics with little regard for the NDA. Start at the bottom and work up.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty impressed with http://www.appsamuck.com/

A new iPhone app is written everyday, and listed on the site with source code and screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

this is probably a good place to start

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Answer (score 1):

Craig Hockenberry (developer of Twitterrific) blogs about iPhone development issues at [furbo.org](http://furbo.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Apple now has developer forums, accessible to registered developers: https://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

My friend suggested me this site edumobile which provides you with detailed information on iPhone development it is significantly a useful resource hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials you will find a lots of good tutorials, and you will be up to date with new iOS features as soon as Apple release then.